# Angularjs output an xml file from a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, angularjs

I have a rails app that I am trying to integrate Angular into. The main function of this application is to fill out forms and press a button to export the form into an xml document. There is no DB so I'm having trouble using the 'new' action (which exports the Xml) on the backend. I don't believe I even need the old rails controllers for this endeavor.

I can't seem to find any tutorials or documentation (that I understand) on the subject. There is plenty on parsing incoming requests but all I need to do is download the form from the current template and am very stuck. Any help would be great!

Comment: this might help... [angular-xml](https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking at the ReadMe it seems that this will take XML responses and turn them into Json. I'm looking for something that will take form responses on a given template and generate an Xml file.

Comment: Form response would be json or some other format??

Comment: Xml, the ordinal app used nokogiri to generate the files. Was wondering if there was something similar that can be used in the front end.